# Issue with PS1 File running as System

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am trying to execute a PS1 file that uses the new PS 5.1 cmdlet Remove-LocalUser and am running into some issues.  Below is the code block that I am running which will check for any local accounts in the Administrator group and then delete them if they are not in the $IgnoreList:

```
$ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue"
Stop-Transcript | out-null
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
Start-Transcript -path C:\BigFix\AdminAccounts\output.txt -append

$users = Get-WmiObject win32_groupuser | Where-Object { $_.GroupComponent -match ‘administrators’ } | ForEach-Object {[wmi]$_.PartComponent }
$IgnoreList = "SOMEACCOUNTNAME"

#Write-host $users.name


:OuterLoop
foreach ($user in $users) {
    foreach ($account in $IgnoreList) {
        if ($user.name -like "$account") {
            continue OuterLoop
        }
    }

    Remove-LocalUser -Name $user.Name
    }
Stop-Transcript
```

This script runs fine on the target machine if I am logged in to a local admin account but will not run when deployed through our End Point management console where it runs as the system account.

The machine in question is running the following version of PS:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                                                                                 
PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1005                                                                                                                        
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                               
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                               
BuildVersion                   10.0.14409.1005                                                                                                                       
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.36373                                                                                                                       
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                   
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                   
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Here is the output of the transcript file when run by the System account:

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20170213172829
Username: **DOMAIN**\SYSTEM
RunAs User: **DOMAIN**\SYSTEM
Machine: QA-G2-CUCNOV-V4 (Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1)
Host Application: powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -NonInteractive -NoProfile -file c:\BigFix\AdminAccounts\removeAdmins.ps1
Process ID: 3244
PSVersion: 5.1.14409.1005
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.14409.1005
BuildVersion: 10.0.14409.1005
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.36373
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Transcript started, output file is C:\BigFix\AdminAccounts\output.txt
Remove-LocalUser : The term 'Remove-LocalUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
At C:\BigFix\AdminAccounts\removeAdmins.ps1:20 char:5
+     Remove-LocalUser -Name $user.Name
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Remove-LocalUser:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
Remove-LocalUser : The term 'Remove-LocalUser' is not recognized as the name
of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At C:\BigFix\AdminAccounts\removeAdmins.ps1:20 char:5
+     Remove-LocalUser -Name $user.Name
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Remove-LocalUser:String) [], Co
   mmandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Remove-LocalUser : The term 'Remove-LocalUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
At C:\BigFix\AdminAccounts\removeAdmins.ps1:20 char:5
+     Remove-LocalUser -Name $user.Name
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Remove-LocalUser:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
Remove-LocalUser : The term 'Remove-LocalUser' is not recognized as the name
of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At C:\BigFix\AdminAccounts\removeAdmins.ps1:20 char:5
+     Remove-LocalUser -Name $user.Name
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Remove-LocalUser:String) [], Co
   mmandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Remove-LocalUser : The term 'Remove-LocalUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
At C:\BigFix\AdminAccounts\removeAdmins.ps1:20 char:5
+     Remove-LocalUser -Name $user.Name
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Remove-LocalUser:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
Remove-LocalUser : The term 'Remove-LocalUser' is not recognized as the name
of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At C:\BigFix\AdminAccounts\removeAdmins.ps1:20 char:5
+     Remove-LocalUser -Name $user.Name
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Remove-LocalUser:String) [], Co
   mmandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Remove-LocalUser : The term 'Remove-LocalUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
At C:\BigFix\AdminAccounts\removeAdmins.ps1:20 char:5
+     Remove-LocalUser -Name $user.Name
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Remove-LocalUser:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
Remove-LocalUser : The term 'Remove-LocalUser' is not recognized as the name
of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At C:\BigFix\AdminAccounts\removeAdmins.ps1:20 char:5
+     Remove-LocalUser -Name $user.Name
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Remove-LocalUser:String) [], Co
   mmandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20170213172829
**********************
```

Any thoughts on why this may be happening would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I do not have powershell 5.0 to validate this but you can write line to import Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts module at begining of your script and then try.

Comment: I added the Import-Module command and that is now causing an error as well:

`Import-Module : The specified module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts' was not loaded because no valid module file 
was found in any module directory.
`
When the command is run in the Shell locally it loads the Module fine

Comment: What is the OS of the machine on which you are running this script?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional and POS Ready 7.  Both give the same error.

Comment: below might be the reason. NOTES

The PrincipalSource property is a property on LocalUser, LocalGroup, and LocalPrincipal objects that describes the source of the object. **PrincipalSource is supported only by Windows 10, Windows Server 2016, and later versions of the Windows operating system. For earlier versions, the property is blank.** Check article [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/remove-localuser)

Comment: That would not explain why it works just fine if run under anything other than the System account though.  Also, I don't believe I am even relying on the PrincipalSource property